# Add the elements value in a list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists

```
populate_name = ['jack', 'Jill', 'Mary', 'Franco', 'jack', 'James', 'Dan', 'Mary']
populate_qty = ['2', '3', '1', '3', '4', '4', '3', '3']
```

I want to output the name whose cumulatively added `qty` is maximum.

In this case:

```
jack = (2 + 4)  # 6
Jill = 3
Mary = (1 + 3)  # 4
Franco = 3
James = 4
Dan = 3
```

The winner here is `jack`, so how do I print out the name, i.e `jack` and its value i.e `6`.

I tried to run through the list and find the occurrences of each of the elements using `populate_name.count(populate_name)` but that's just to find the occurrence. Moreover it will repeat if I run the for loop in the entire `range(len(populate_name))`.

**NOTE**

The populate_name and populate_qty in the actual code consists of more than 1K elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Python built-in function [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and the [**`dict`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict) data structure to get your result:

```
result = {}
for name, qty in zip(populate_name, populate_qty):
    result[name] = result.get(name, 0) + int(qty)

name, qty = sorted(result.items(), key=lambda o: o[1])[-1]
```

So then you get your winner:

```
>>> print(name)  # name
'jack'
>>> print(qty)  # qty
6
```

Comment: And how do I get the qty i.e. for `jack`

Comment: I get the same error when i run the code, similar to what I added for nneonneo answer i.e   ` result[name] = result.get(name, 0) + qty
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' `  . Any missing module?

Comment: do you use the exact same lists that you have posted?

Comment: No. The one in the code is a big list with more than 1K elements.

Comment: That is most probably a problem with your data. I suppose you have a string value somewhere in your `populate_qty`. you can modify the code inside for loop to `result[name] = result.get(name, 0) + int(qty)`, if the erroneous string value is a number string. If it works, then you may consider fixing your data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81096/discussion-between-n9code-and-learning).

Answer (score 3):

Use `collections.Counter`!

```
import collections

counter = collections.Counter()

for name, qty in zip(populate_name, populate_qty):
    counter[name] += qty

print counter.most_common()[0][0]
```

Comment: I receive following error message  `counter[name] += qty
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str `

Comment: Odd, `qty` should be an int unless you put the wrong values in.

Comment: Edited the questio. Sorry the elements in populate_qty are strings.

Comment: Then add `int(qty)` instead of `qty`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator

def max_populate(populate_name, populate_qty):
    d = {}
    for i in zip(populate_name, populate_qty):
        if i in d:
            d[i[0]] += i[1]
        else:
            d[i[0]] = i[1]
    return max(d.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.6 and it throws, `NameError: global name 'operator' is not defined`

Comment: `import operator` I also use python 2.7